# Jquery splits huge array into many new callbacks while parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays, json

I stumbled upon a small problem.
I get back an JSON response which includes a byte array with 67615 entries.
Now well it adds a

```
`[....,154,156,);jQuery1910039778258679286416_1363006432850(181,104,...]
```

every ~7300 characters

Now when i use the ajax method to parse it how it normaly works it gives me an error because the callbacks invalidate the response 
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

...,184,1,26,65,140,86,211,16,194,210,174,1);jQuery17203250109862964784_13639643449...

so its not valid anymore

I use this to parse it

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    cache : false,
    dataType : "jsonp",
    crossDomain : true,
    success : function(root) {
        console.log(root)

    }
})
```

Could this be a problem with the asp server giving me the object or is there something wrong with the parsing?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT1:

```
   [WebMethod(Description = " ", EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public Borrower getSessionedBorrowerHeader(ref sysmessage aMessage)
{
    if (!(userValidated(ref aMessage)))
        return null;
    BorrowerControl borrowerControl = new BorrowerControl(LOCALconnectionStringDb,
                                                          WEBconnectionStringDb,
                                                          STATSconnectionStringDb,
                                                          LIBconnectionStringDb,
                                                          CATconnectionStringDb,
                                                          LIBconnectionStringDb,
                                                          Session);
    Borrower returnObj = borrowerControl.getSessionedBorrowerHeader(ref aMessage);
    borrowerControl.Dispose();
    return returnObj;
}
```

if you need more code tell me im not into ASP :(

EDIT2:

http://pastebin.com/e3X2VKxY

What to do:(
Here is the JSON answer

Comment: What's generating the JSON? Is this happening at line breaks?

Comment: the Json gets generated by the asp.net server running here if i call some object without the bytearray it works fine just the bytearray makes it fail even though the array is just plain data. The JSON gets serialized by the .NET on its own using    ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json

Comment: It looks like ASP is breaking the response into multiple callbacks. You could use native javascript to make the jsonp request and receive all those callbacks, but if you want jQuery to handle it, you'll have to have it not split it up.

Comment: I'm not into JS thats the problem else I would use it as I see no option to make ASP not split it?

Comment: You'll probably have to share some of the ASP code here for anyone to answer that.

Comment: @Blazemonger edited it in if you need more

Comment: It's supposed to be JSONP, not JSON, isn't it?

Comment: Only jsonp adds a callback parameter, e.g. the `jQueryNUMBER` or what you define in the `jsonpCallback` parameter. If not required, you could use simple json to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Yes, you should set datatype to "json" instead of "jsonp", unless you have a strong requirement to use JSONP, and check whether that does solve your problem. Otherwise you need to rebuild the object received from the server (you can probably use jQuery to do that...)

Comment: Well i do not know why but if I use json it does not work at all anymore it will just add some Random _1238832848723874 at the end of the url

Comment: Why not try specifying 'html' as the ajax return dataType - then you can rule out if it is being rendered by the server or by the json encoding?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ASP limiting factor. This is not jQuery specific, but for any JSON response from the ASP server. I've seen this on ColdFusion servers too. Find this setting and see if the limit you have correlates to your limit you hit. See if you can increase it to what you need.

```
<system.web.extensions>  
    <scripting>  
        <webServices>  
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="x"></jsonSerialization>  
        </webServices>  
    </scripting>  
</system.web.extensions>
```

If you don't have access to the server settings, you may also be able to set the value in your code. Here is an MSDN reference for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx

It also states there:

> The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data.

This is way over your length of ~7300 characters. But perhaps someone has adjusted this setting.

I also am curious that you see 'multiple' returns to the call back method. Normally, I think, this limit will simply truncate the result of the first callback result.
Maybe you also have something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery documentation, you can set the name of the jsonp callback, to save bytes in your case: `jsonpCallback`

```
function J() { ... }
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    cache : false,
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback : "J",
    crossDomain : true,
    success : function(root) {
        console.log(root)
    }
})
```

Comment: I doubt this will reduce 67k entries down to 7.3k characters or less

Comment: Can you provide the full JSON response, or at least something that is structurally equivalent?